# Reference documentation for cgroups (control groups) settings

Tags: linux, documentation, cgroups, lxc

I'm looking for some reference documentation to explain what each of the settings are, for each control group.

For example, there's `cpuset.cpus`, I think setting this to `0` means use all CPUs, setting it to `1` limits you to `1` core. And `cpuset.shares`, how is that configured exactly?

Surely there's a reference doc that simply explains each of the settings somewhere right? Anyone have a link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A big thanks to Red Hat, I finally tracked down the reference documentation I was looking for in their documentation. I expect that there's no difference between Red Hat and other distros on this point.

[Subsystems and Tunable Parameters | Red Hat Customer Portal](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Resource_Management_Guide/ch-Subsystems_and_Tunable_Parameters.html)

Answer (score 2):

`cgroups` is still quite in flux in the Linux kernel. Probably the best documentation is [LWN](http://lwn.net)'s coverage, perhaps [H-online](http://www.h-online.com/) or [Kernelnewbies](http://kernelnewbies.org) have something to say. Currently [systemd](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd) is the most prolific user.